# Is there any way to bypass MFA Authentication for Selenium Test Cases ? apart from disabling the MFA for test account

Tags: selenium-webdriver, azure-automation, multi-factor-authentication

Using Selenium when we are opening one URL and enters email id and click on submit button then the URL redirects to Microsoft login where it ask for MFA code from authenticator app. When using Selenium it is not possible to provide the MFA code with out manual intervention in the script because the MFA code changes every 30 seconds.

There are some way outs are given in the Selenium official website such as -

1. Disable MFA for certain users in test env.
2. Disable MFA for test env.

these are temporary solution but these are coming with other security issues. So these cant be a permanent solution. Also not automating a website which has MFA is not a solution.

Please comment if anyone has automate MFA using Selenium or any other test automation tool. Or if any way is there to automate MFA based Websites.

I am expecting to automate MFA, or somehow bypass the MFA using some valid resources not by disabling MFA in test environment or for certain users in test environment.

Comment: If you use a web-based e-mail client you may be able to automate getting the MFA code from the e-mail.

Comment: According to the Microsoft documentation, MFA is designed to be a security feature that requires manual intervention, and there is no way to bypass it using valid resources. The only options mentioned in the Selenium official website are to disable MFA for certain users in the test environment or to disable MFA for the test environment, but these are temporary solutions that come with other security issues and are not recommended as permanent solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have the capability to change the MFA flow from Time-based OTP to SMS-based MFA.

In our case, we configured the users we use to automate test cases to use SMS-based MFA codes.

When the test tries to login, it sends an MFA code to a phone number which stores the value in a database and we can query this value through an API. The service we use for that is called [GetMyMFA](http://get.mymfa.io) but multiple other services exist in order to meet this need.

I hope you can figure out a way to work it out like this.

All the best

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use totp protocol! There are plenty of libs on the web with workinstruction in java/python/javascript which support that, so sms is not perse needed
pseudocode in javascript

```
const totp = require("totp-generator");


const token = totp("JBSWY3DPEHPK3PXP"); //secret which you can copy from your phone, then it will provide you a 6 digit number which you can use to enter

console.log(token);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this problem. My solution was to get a n MFA code once and save all of the cookies to text files, and reload them when using selenium so that the instance of edge driver does not redirect to the MS site for a new code each time. I will have to get a new code every 60 days (or sooner if I choose to).